# Crash while calling boost io_context run()

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using boost::process library to run different sub-processes from my main process. Recently we have updated to boost 1.77 version from previous 1.71 version. After the update my tool is crashing when io_context run() function is called. The call is made like below.

```
    namespace bp = boost::process;
    namespace ba = boost::asio;
    ba::io_context _ios;
    _child = new bp::child(execPath,
            _args,
            bp::on_exit=[this](int exit_code, const std::error_code& ec){onExit(exit_code, ec);},
            bp::std_out > _outHandler,
            bp::std_err > _errHandler,
            bp::std_in.close(),
            _ios);
    _ios.run();
```

Going deep into the trace it shows that it crashes while calling free() in boost::asio::aligned_delete funtion. Also the crash occurs before the exit handler is called. Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. See [ask] for more information. Until you do that, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to answer your question.

Comment: We need more code. What is `_outHandler`/`_errHandler`? It can be many things. (Also, why are you storing `_child` and allocating dynamically? It completes - by definition - before `_ios.run()` returns.

Answer (score 1):

Because the code is not enough to diagnose the problem off, here's what I imagined the surrounding code to be like, so you can compare notes.

This code has no problems:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96bb945272f36743)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace bp = boost::process;
namespace ba = boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;

struct X {
    boost::filesystem::path execPath{"/bin/bash"};
    std::vector<std::string> _args{
        "-c",
        "sort -R /etc/dictionaries-common/words | head -30 | nl"};
    std::future<std::string> _outHandler, _errHandler;

    void foo() {
        ba::io_context _ios;
        bp::child child(
            execPath,
            _args,
            bp::on_exit =
                [this](int exit_code, error_code ec)
            {
                onExit(exit_code, ec);
            },
            bp::std_out > _outHandler,
            bp::std_err > _errHandler,
            bp::std_in.close(),
            _ios);
        std::cout << "Before run" << std::endl;
        _ios.run();
        std::cout << "After run" << std::endl;
    }

    void onExit(int exit_code, error_code ec)
    {
        std::cout << "Exited with: " << exit_code << " ("
                  << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    x.foo();
    std::cout << "err: " << std::quoted(x._errHandler.get()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "out: " << std::quoted(x._outHandler.get()) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
Before run
Exited with: 0 (Success)
After run
err: ""
out: "     1    mainframe
     2  congenital
     3  entrusted
     4  employing
     5  sheepishly
     6  denuding
     7  abjuration
     8  descant
     9  brawn's
    10  happier
    11  activism
    12  Cheops
    13  Taiwan's
    14  sublimated
    15  cardigans
    16  Triton's
    17  atlas's
    18  penning
    19  stink
    20  forefeet
    21  fusses
    22  spectrum's
    23  reoccupy
    24  replicate
    25  rectors
    26  preventives
    27  catacomb's
    28  untainted
    29  eightieth
    30  testing
"
```

Like I said, there's not much use extending the lifetime of `child` but you **can**. If you replace that line with just

```
    new bp::child( 
         // ... the same
```

everything works the same (though obviously the `bp::child` instance is leaked)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, That's pretty much the simple version of the process launcher code with the same data structures as mentioned in the code. Although the crash doesn't happen in the simpler version for me too as I tried it earlier also. There is a lot of code surrounding this which ideally should not affect this part. Only when the the code is run as part of tool it crashes here. In previous boost version it worked fine. I suspect it might be because of some conflicting library dependencies but not able to figure it out.